# Why ZXING Camera doesnt show in higher API 25 or higher

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, device, zxing

I have two android phone Samsung S5 API 19 and and another device API 25. In my case I develop scanner using ZXING and it successfully show the camera and working in device API 19 but when I test in in higher version of device Android Nougat API 25 . The application doesn't show the camera. I change my target sdk into API 26 but still not working, I checked Manifest and I also declare the camera permission. Please help me.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.copy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

        //scanner camera library
        compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

        //sweetalert dialog library
        compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'

        //login and retrieving data library
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add runtime permission for camera to make it work on devices with api levels >= 23(Marshmallow 6.0).
Try [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions). This will be easy to use and you can quickly get set go.

Comment: I resolved my problem by giving the camera permision in Xiaomi phone. Xiaomi devices have unique security. Read this http://xiaomiadvices.com/miui7-enable-permission-manager-xiaomi-mi-redmi-phones/